# Net Core cookie sliding expiration problem for long running requests

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

We have an .Net Core application with a controller action which takes a lot of time to complete.

We use cookies with sliding expiration for authentication:

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Controller with time-consuming action is:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LongRunning()
    {
        // Some code which takes more time to complete than cookie lifetime
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

        return Ok("Completed");
    }
}
```

The problem is when a "LongRunning" action is called after 8 minutes of inactivity (more then half-way of cookie expiration window), then cookie returned from the server will contain an expired authentication ticket.

It seems that .Net Core calculates a new ticket expiration time before executing of action, but actually sets cookie with the ticket after action completes and browser receives cookie with ticket which have already expired.

.Net Core version: 5.0

Is it possible to configure authentication middleware to calculate ticket expiration time *after* action completes? Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1648),and maybe you can set the cookie to expire in a longer time.

Comment: I agree, it can work as a workaround. But because of security requirements we should avoid extending of cookie lifetime